# Package name must not contain underscore (cannot be auto-corrected) com.amazonaws.amplify.amplify_datastore

Tags: android, flutter, aws-amplify

Amplify datastore is not working for my flutter project for android. When building the project using `./gradlew build` I get this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':amplify_datastore:ktlintTestSourceSetFormat'.


> A failure occurred while executing org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint.worker.ConsoleReportWorkAction
> KtLint found code style violations. Please see the following reports:
> \- /Users/seanbrown/project/watmobiledev/build/amplify_datastore/reports/ktlint/ktlintTestSourceSetFormat/ktlintTestSourceSetFormat.txt
```

upon closer inspection when running `./gradlew ktlintFormat` it's because the amplify datastore package has a underscore in it.

`/Users/seanbrown/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/amplify_datastore-1.4.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/amazonaws/amplify/amplify_datastore/types/hub/FlutterSubscriptionsEstablishedEvent.kt:4:1 Package name must not contain underscore (cannot be auto-corrected)`
Has anyone seen this issue before?

1. I've update the amplify_datastore dependency in my pubspec.yaml file to   amplify_datastore: ^1.4.0

- I believed it was caused by an outdated version

2. I've deleted my android/ directory and run flutter create . to get a fresh start

- Sometimes in flutter starting over fixes a bunch of issues

3. Followed the amplify documentation for setting up android project. [instructions](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/project-setup/platform-setup/q/platform/flutter/#android)

here's part of the log output:

```
[90m/Users/seanbrown/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/amplify_datastore-1.5.0/android/src/test/kotlin/com/amazonaws/amplify/amplify_datastore/[0mAmplifyDataStoreHubTest.kt[90m:[0m1[90m:1:[0m File 'AmplifyDataStoreHubTest.kt' contains a single class and possibly also extension functions for that class and should be named same after that class 'Amplify_DataStoreHubTest.kt' [90m(filename)[0m
[90m/Users/seanbrown/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/amplify_datastore-1.5.0/android/src/test/kotlin/com/amazonaws/amplify/amplify_datastore/[0mAmplifyDataStoreHubTest.kt[90m:[0m4[90m:1:[0m Package name must not contain underscore [90m(package-name)[0m
[90m/Users/seanbrown/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/amplify_datastore-1.5.0/android/src/test/kotlin/com/amazonaws/amplify/amplify_datastore/[0mAmplifyDataStoreHubTest.kt[90m:[0m75[90m:1:[0m Unexpected indentation (16) (should be 12) [90m(indent)[0m
[90m/Users/seanbrown/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/amplify_datastore-1.5.0/android/src/test/kotlin/com/amazonaws/amplify/amplify_datastore/[0mAmplifyDataStoreHubTest.kt[90m:[0m76[90m:1:[0m Unexpected indentation (20) (should be 16) [90m(indent)[0m
[90m/Users/seanbrown/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/amplify_datastore-1.5.0/android/src/test/kotlin/com/amazonaws/amplify/amplify_datastore/[0mAmplifyDataStoreHubTest.kt[90m:[0m77[90m:1:[0m Unexpected indentation (20) (should be 16) [90m(indent)[0m
[90m/Users/seanbrown/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/amplify_datastore-1.5.0/android/src/test/kotlin/com/amazonaws/amplify/amplify_datastore/[0mAmplifyDataStoreHubTest.kt[90m:[0m78[90m:1:[0m Unexpected indentation (20) (should be 16) [90m(indent)[0m
[90m/Users/seanbrown/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/amplify_datastore-1.5.0/android/src/test/kotlin/com/amazonaws/amplify/amplify_datastore/[0mAmplifyDataStoreHubTest.kt[90m:[0m79[90m:1:[0m Unexpected indentation (16) (should be 12) [90m(indent)[0m
[90m/Users/seanbrown/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/amplify_datastore-1.5.0/android/src/test/kotlin/com/amazonaws/amplify/amplify_datastore/[0mAmplifyDataStoreHubTest.kt[90m:[0m80[90m:1:[0m Unexpected indentation (16) (should be 12) [90m(indent)[0m
[90m/Users/seanbrown/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/amplify_datastore-1.5.0/android/src/test/kotlin/com/amazonaws/amplify/amplify_datastore/[0mAmplifyDataStoreHubTest.kt[90m:[0m124[90m:1:[0m Unexpected indentation (16) (should be 12) [90m(indent)[0m
[90m/Users/seanbrown/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/amplify_datastore-1.5.0/android/src/test/kotlin/com/amazonaws/amplify/amplify_datastore/[0mAmplifyDataStoreHubTest.kt[90m:[0m125[90m:1:[0m Unexpected indentation (20) (should be 16) [90m(indent)[0m
[90m/Users/seanbrown/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/amplify_datastore-1.5.0/android/src/test/kotlin/com/amazonaws/amplify/amplify_datastore/[0mAmplifyDataStoreHubTest.kt[90m:[0m126[90m:1:[0m Unexpected indentation (20) (should be 16) [90m(indent)[0m
```

Comment: "it's because the amplify datastore package has a underscore in it" What specifically led you to that conclusion?

Comment: @jamesdlin, running ```./gradlew build```  will cause a klint test to fail. the output of that error is ```/Users/seanbrown/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/amplify_datastore-1.4.2/android/src/main/kotlin/com/amazonaws/amplify/amplify_datastore/types/hub/FlutterSubscriptionsEstablishedEvent.kt:4:1 Package name must not contain underscore (cannot be auto-corrected)```

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation I can build and run the app on android devices but I can't run `./gradlew build` without it failing at this test.

I'm still not sure how to fix the error but I just sync and release the app via android studio instead of using `flutter build appbundle` for now.

Comment: Its not an answer its comment/observation note